# Visual Studio C++ outputting strange character to console when using template

Tags: c++, templates, character

I'm running into a problem when I try to output certain characters to the console with VS 2013.

Here's an image of what the character looks like (after the 2) [image]. I've tested with the "+-/*" symbols, and it happens with each of them.

Basically, my program uses a stack class that is a template to save characters, and then pulls those characters later on. Here is my stack class.

```
#include <assert.h>

template <class Item>
class stack
{
public:
    //TYPEDEFS AND MEMBER CONSTANT
    typedef int size_type; 
    typedef Item value_type;
    static const size_type CAPACITY = 30;
    //Constructor
    stack() { used = 0; } //Postcondition: The stack has been initialized as an empty stack.
    //Modification member functions
    void push(const Item& entry); //Precondition: size() < CAPACITY. Postcondition: A new copy of entry has been pushed onto the stack.
    void pop(); //Precondition: size() > 0. Postcondition:The top item of the stack has been removed.
    //Constant member functions
    bool empty() const { return (used == 0); } //Postcondition: The return value is true if the stack is empty, and false otherwise.
    size_type size() const { return used; } //Postcondition: The return value is the total number of items in the stack.
    Item top() const; //Precondition: size() > 0. Postcondition: The return value is the top item of the stack, but the stack is unchanged. This differs slightly from the STL stack (where the top function returns a reference to the item on top of the stack).
private:
    Item data[CAPACITY]; //Partially filled array.
    size_type used;
};

template <class Item>
void stack<Item>::push(const Item& entry) {
    assert(size() < CAPACITY);
    data[used] = entry;
    used++;
}

template <class Item>
void stack<Item>::pop() {
    assert(size() > 0);
    used--;
}

template <class Item>
Item stack<Item>::top() const {
    assert(size() > 0);
    return data[used];
}
```

And then my driver uses `myStack.push(pString[pos]);` to save a character, which it later outputs with `cout << myStack.top();`

Does anyone know how to make it show the correct characters? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
template <class Item>
Item stack<Item>::top() const {
    assert(size() > 0);
    return data[used];
}
```

will return one past the end, since `used` == `size()`. You want:

```
return data[used - 1];
```

Comment: Oh, wow, you're right. I can't believe that I overlooked that.